# What combination of skills and or spells can remove a creature's endoskeleton while in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

As the title says.

The reason I am asking a question, is for a few reasons:

1. Creature immobilization
2. Death
3. Intimidation
4. Inducing fear of the creatures allies
5. Crowd control

*If I were to pull this off without removing the endoskeleton , I would Hold Person/Creature to paralyze them, then alter memory, but I don't know how the creature would react once hold wears off.*

Comment: Uh... Wha? O_o?

Comment: Thanks for being so welcoming, and editing my question. I joined because I had a question regarding True Polymorph but I answered my question, by reading the spell enough times. There doesn't seem to be a place here to post it, but if a question comes up, I am pretty sure I'll have an awesome answer for them. I look forward to being here!

Comment: @Griblet If you've answered your own question, you are allowed (and encouraged) to post your solution as an answer, in order to help future readers with skeleton extractions.

Comment: @JustinKrejcha That's very kind, I like to think this place is an advanced form of "ducking", where you talk to an inanimate object and you solve your answer by just taking the time to go over the question. You people are awesome!

Comment: Glad to help! Though I didn't actually do anything myself :P

Comment: You should only ask [practical, answerable questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) based on actual problems that you face. What problem are you trying to solve by "removing a creature's skeleton"?

Comment: This is D&D; removing an opponent's skeleton is a real problem that may need solving. A third edition prestige class called the Osteomancer could remove a creature's skeleton, while a creature called the Bone Ooze had a similar ability.

Comment: If we get a resolution to this, My follow up question is if I can animate the skeleton that has been removed....

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can cast Polymorph and turn them into an octopus (or some other invertebrate).